# Why is mocha test throwing "Error done() called multiple times in hook <"before each" ....>?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, smartcontracts, web3js, ganache

I am learning about smart contracts and blockchain development. I am currently trying to test the deployment of a simple contract using mocha but when running the test the following error is thrown :

> Error: done() called multiple times in hook <"before each" hook for "deploys contract"> (of root suite)
> at createMultipleDoneError (/Users/nacholopez/Desktop/Inbox/node_modules/mocha/lib/errors.js:428:13)
> at multiple (/Users/nacholopez/Desktop/Inbox/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:290:24)
> at done (/Users/nacholopez/Desktop/Inbox/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:301:14)
> at /Users/nacholopez/Desktop/Inbox/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:371:11
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
> code: 'ERR_MOCHA_MULTIPLE_DONE',
> valueType: 'undefined',
> value: undefined

Here is my compilation and testing code:

compile.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const solc = require('solc');
const Inboxpath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'Inbox.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(Inboxpath, 'utf8');

const input = {
    language: "Solidity",
    sources: {
        "Inbox.sol": {
            content: source,
        },
    },
    settings: {
        outputSelection: {
            "*": {
                "*": ["*"],
            },
        },
    },
};
const output = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input)));

module.exports = output.contracts["Inbox.sol"].Inbox;
```

Inbox.test.js :

```
const assert = require('assert');
const ganache = require('ganache-cli');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider());
const { abi, evm } = require('../compile');

let accounts;
let inbox;

beforeEach(async () => {
    accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    inbox = await new web3.eth.Contract(abi).
        deploy({ data: evm.bytecode.object, arguments: ['hi there'] }).
        send({ from: accounts[0], gas: '1000000' });
});

describe('Inbox', () => {
    it('deploys contract', () => {
        console.log(inbox);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue as well and I made the callback to the 'it' function 'async' and that fixed the issue for me.

```
it("deploys a contract", async () => {
        assert.ok(inbox.options.address);
    });
```